npx hanging during initialization of react, expo, and next app
I am currently experiencing an issue where the following commands (and potentially more) hang indefinitely when trying to initialize a project:

npx create-react-app
npx create-expo-app
npx create-next-app

Here is an example:
C:\Users\james\Documents>npx create-expo-app@latest my-app

And then it plays the spinning progress wheel animation (|/-|) ~2 times, and is stuck without any progress indefinitely. I have left it alone for hours and nothing happened. Ctrl + C works at terminating the batch job.
Here is some of what I have tried to fix the issue:

Restart my computer (several times)
Uninstall and reinstall Node.js multiple times (including once with fnm Fast Node Manager)
Install different version of Node.js (including v18.20.4 LTS, v20.15.1 LTS, and v22.5.0
Tried the commands from Windows CMD (as well as running it as admin), Windows Powershell, and from VS Code
Tried to set registry using npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global (still the same issue)
Tried to clear cache npm cache clear --force (still the same issue)
Install create-expo-app globally and then use it (still the same issue)
I even tried installing it with Yarn... unfortunately, that came with a whole page of repeated warnings like these:

warning expo > @expo/cli > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

warning expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.

warning expo > @expo/cli > @expo/rudder-sdk-node > @expo/bunyan > mv > rimraf@2.4.5: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported

warning expo > @expo/cli > @expo/rudder-sdk-node > @expo/bunyan > mv > rimraf > glob > inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.

warning "expo > babel-preset-expo > @react-native/babel-preset > @react-native/babel-plugin-codegen > @react-native/codegen > jscodeshift@0.14.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.1.6".

And then the yarn command gets stuck at an empty progress bar:
[---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/719

Please help 
Current system information:
Windows 11

> node -v
v22.5.0

>npm -v
10.8.2

npx create-expo-app@latest my-app hangs and gets stuck without any progress

I'm having the same issue. I wonder if there is an upstream issue. Something it is trying to install. Is there a way you know of to get more verbose install output?

Just found out, in Windows Powershell, you can enable verbose-like output for create-expo-app with $env:DEBUG="*", and then run npx create-expo-app my-app.
Here is my output:
expo:init:cli Default args:
expo:init:cli { _: [ 'my-app' ] } +0ms
expo:init:cli Parsed:
expo:init:cli { args: {}, projectRoot: 'my-app' } +8ms
And then it hangs :(

@DylanRussell Since we have similar problems, I'm curious, do you also have a problem with npm install? I was trying to play around with npm today when I tried npm install react-native, and it hangs too. Enabling verbose output reveals that the install almost always hangs when it tries to fetch eastasianwidth or path-exists.

Hey sorry man, I pretty much immediately went on vacation after replying to you and just got back. Did you every figure out an answer? Tried to create a Next app today and having the same issue.

oh shoot, i fixed it. Update your node to v22.6.0 (nvm install node). Everything works for me now.

Oh I tried that too but it didn’t work. However, it turned out for me that for some reason npm wouldn’t run in my Documents folder, which was super weird. I was switching directories within my documents, but it didn’t matter. Eventually I just created a new folder in my root and it worked there (idk why). Glad to hear you got it working though.

I just installed node v22.5.1 and it started working no hanging so that's the fix I guess

Please provide  other details, to help others in a unambiguously  way. "I guess" fits well in a comment, not in an answer. Please read how to answer. Thank you
